# Servlet Testing

Tags: java, testing, servlets, jetty

I am using the [ServletTester](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/ServletTester) class provided by Jetty to test one of my servlets.

The servlet reads the the body of the request using InputStream.read() to construct a byte[] which is the decoded and acted on by the servlet.

The ServletTest class provides a method getResponses(ByteArrayBuffer) but I'm unsure how to create one of these in the correct format since it would also need to contain things like headers (e.g. "Content-Type: application/octet-stream).

Can anyone show me an easy way to construct this, preferably using an existing library so that I can use it in a similar way to the [HttpTester](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/ServletTester) class.

If there is a "better" way to test servlets (ideally using a local connector rather than via the tcp stack) I'd like to hear that also.

Many thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why use a mock at all? Why not test the servlet by running it in jetty?

```
Servlet servlet = new MyServlet();
String mapping = "/foo";

    Server server = new Server(0);
    Context servletContext = new Context(server, contextPath, Context.SESSIONS);
    servletContext.addServlet(new ServletHolder(servlet), mapping);
    server.start();

    URL url = new URL("http", "localhost", server.getConnectors()[0].getLocalPort(), "/foo?bar");

    //get the url...assert what you want

    //finally server.stop();
```

Edit: Just wanting to reassure people that this is very fast. Its also a very reliable indicator of what your code will actually do, because it is in fact doing it.

Comment: I took a look at the servlet tester, and it kind of does this... But I don't like the API much.

Answer (score 3):

Spring MVC provides [a small set of "mock" classes](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/mock/web/package-summary.html) for the various `javax.servlet` interfaces, such as `HttpServletRequest`, `HttpSession`, and so on. This makes it easy to unit test the likes of a servlet, you just inject mocks into the e.g. `doGet()` method.

Even if you don't use Spring itself on the server, you can still use the mock from the library, just for your tests.

Answer (score 1):

You can use HttpClient to simplify testing somewhat.  Take a look at the following article:

http://roberthanson.blogspot.com/2007/12/testing-servlets-with-junit.html

That in combination with servlet tester should give you what you want unit test wise.